# How to assembly maven project using jarjar format?

Tags: java, maven, uberjar, jarjar

I tried some assembly plugins like `maven-assembly-plugin` , `maven-shading-plugin` but none of them support `jarjar` file format.

So is there a maven plugin to assembly Uber-Jar by `jarjar` file format?

It's helpful to avoid resources conflicts like [`spring.handlers`,`spring.schemas`]

Comment: The questions is what you understand by *jarjar* format?

Comment: @khmarbaise What I wanna do is exacatly like we export `Runnable JAR` with library jars inside generated package by Eclipse. Then i realized this file format maybe `JarJar`

Comment: see my answer. The maven-shade produces a jar file which is called ueber-jar.

Answer (score 0):

The [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) supports the creation of ueber-jar furthermore the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) also supports that but a little bit simpler.